# How to ignore collisions but raise the trigger event in unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an enemy collider 2D and player collider2D. I need player to be possible to go through enemy. I set Physics2D to

```
Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(10 (Player layer), 12(Enemie layer));
```

But I still need event which shows that player interacted with enemy. I added trigger on enemy, but OnTriggerEnter2D() function isn't working

Comment: It sounds like your problem is in your `OnTriggerEnter2D()` method. Could you provide that in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you ignore the layers?

**You need them to "collide" with each other in order to have trigger events as well!**

The `Collision Matrix` should rather be read as "Interaction Matrix" and `IgnoreLayerCollision` rather as "Ignore Layer Interaction".

You rather want to enable [`Collider2D.isTrrigger`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D-isTrigger.html) so objects can pass this collider but still receive trigger events **as long as you fulfill the conditions** listed in the [Collision Action Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)